# How to extract hour (or minutes, or seconds) as integer from a timestamp ksqldb?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Giving a timestamp in the format say "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" is it possible to extract hour as an integer in kqsldb? E.g. is the something similer to the MySQL function HOUR() in ksqldb?
Example:
running
HOUR(TIMESTAMP(22,59,01))
would return 22.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a function named HOUR - [here](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/#datetostring) is the list of date and time scalar functions.

You may be able to use `TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' [, TIMEZONE])` function to convert the timestamp to string and then use `SUBSTRING(token, start, end)` function to extract the hour part.

Comment: It would be better to parse and reformat any date object incase the string length ever changes